# Fast union of two big lists

Tags: c#, linq, union, plinq

I m using union on two big lists (over 1 million entries) and it s quite slow (a few minutes)
I need the feature to remove duplicates so I cannot use concat and my lists are not sorted.
Is there a faster way? Maybe using `plinq`?

Comment: You'll need to show us your code. Two lists of 1million items should be able to `Union` in <1 second.

Comment: Note that my benchmark which: generates 2 million random ints, unions and dumps the result count runs in `0.083` seconds.

Comment: Psychic debugging: your List contains a custom struct that doesn't implement `Equals` or `GetHashCode`, so you get a default (and slow) implementation provided by the CLR that uses reflection. See http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/02/creating_equatable_objects.html for implementation recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not saying what are your items in the list, but one option is to use proper data structure for this task - you want to only keep unique items - it is definition of SET, so use HashSet.

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(list1);
hashSet.UnionWith(list2);
```

Also I measured time for code above vs Linq.Union:

```
var list3 = list1.Union(list2).Distinct();
```

And here is timing ( HashSet.UnionWith works almost twice faster):

```
HashSet.UnionWith
real    0m4.111s
user    0m3.890s
sys 0m0.132s

real    0m4.562s
user    0m4.074s
sys 0m0.170s

real    0m4.052s
user    0m3.851s
sys 0m0.129s

real    0m4.003s
user    0m3.814s
sys 0m0.125s

real    0m4.058s
user    0m3.858s
sys 0m0.126s


Linq.Union.Distinct
real    0m7.579s
user    0m7.014s
sys 0m0.428s

real    0m7.498s
user    0m6.965s
sys 0m0.419s

real    0m7.596s
user    0m6.994s
sys 0m0.412s

real    0m7.446s
user    0m6.917s
sys 0m0.416s

real    0m7.452s
user    0m6.928s
sys 0m0.403s
```

Comment: I believe `Union` uses a `Set` internally, so the performance should be fairly similar

Comment: @Rob it actually uses internal Set class not HashSet ( https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L3645)  not sure if they have the same performance for `add` operation, let me check.

Comment: @Rob for me UnionWith works 20-25% faster than Linq.Union on Mono.